# How to debug lwc running in iOS salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, lightning-web-components

I am working on a Salesforce app and it is working fine in chrome smart devices mode(Salesforce1) but when I use this app from iOS mobile it is not working fine. Now I want to debug it running on iOS. How to debug?
Thanks in advance.